# Instagram login fields not activated in internet explorer 11 on desktop

Tags: javascript, authentication, internet-explorer, input, instagram

I am using windows 10 on my laptop. My browser is Internet explorer 11
When I go to https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/ I am unable to enter my username & password because the fields are showing but not active. All other websites are working fine on ie 11 except Instagram. Can someone please help me with this.

In the below link I have recorded the issue that I am facing.
https://www.loom.com/share/4d00795ab86243cfb3eefa530839b608

Comment: Install a modern browser. IE 11 doesn't fit that bill

Comment: +1 for the recording. Facebook didn't do their job properly obviously. I guess they don't care about IE visitors since the stats are low

Comment: @charlietfl IE is the most recent browser. I want this to work for a testing purpose. I am using iMacros and because imacros uses IE I am not able to work with iMacros. Is there a way to login through IE some alternative?

Comment: Edge is Microsoft's most recent browser and like the other main browser vendors they  do continual updates

Answer (score 2):

I use F12 dev tools to check the page and find that the login fields are not activated because it uses the `flex` css property. The `flex` property is not so compatible with IE so the `<input>` fields become very small. If we remove the `flex` property then the login fields can show normally: [example demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmQZi.gif).

You could try to untick the `flex` css property using F12 dev tools and login the website to see if this can meet the demand of your test.